# How to add brush background to Hub header to make white text more readable on white background?

Tags: .net, xaml, brush

I have standard `HubPage` with light background. Unfortunatelly `Hub`'s header is very light. How can I make background more dark.
[image]

```
    <Hub>
        <Hub.Header>
            <!-- Back button and page title -->
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Yolo funcy, faded text"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Hub.Header>

        <HubSection Width="780" Margin="0,0,80,0">
            <HubSection.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill"
                   ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/sf.jpg"/>
            </HubSection.Background>
        </HubSection>
     </Hub>
```

I had similar problem with login page, but without `Hub` it was simpler, I just added.

```
<Rectangle
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Grid.RowSpan="9">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="-0.5, 0.25" EndPoint="0.75, 0.75">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a foreground to the textblock?

```
  <Hub.Header>
        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Yolo funcy, faded text" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Hub.Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

In original template of HubSection, header is represented as Button with no special Foreground style.
So you can override default theme brush: *ButtonForegroundThemeBrush*:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
```

Keep in mind that it will change foreground for all buttons with generic style.

Here are other resources for header Button from HubSection template:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HubSectionHeaderPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HubSectionHeaderPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
```